# strange python issue, 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, json, unicode, python-requests

Here is my code and does anyone have any ideas what is wrong? I open [my JSON content](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=library.getartists&api_key=4c22bd45cf5aa6e408e02b3fc1bff690&user=joanofarctan&format=json) directly by browser and it works,

```
data = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=library.getartists&api_key=4c22bd45cf5aa6e408e02b3fc1bff690&user=joanofarctan&format=json').text
data = json.load(data)
print type(data)
return data
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: drop the `json.load`, `requests` objects have a `.json()` method.

Comment: Please remember to upvote helpful answers and [accept the one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/141542) that solved your problem to mark this question as resolved.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This error raised because the `data` is a unicode/str variable, change the second line of your code to resolve your error:

```
data = json.loads(data)
```

`json.load` get a file object in first parameter position and call the `read` method of this.

Also you can call the `json` method of the response to fetch data directly:

```
response = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=library.getartists&api_key=4c22bd45cf5aa6e408e02b3fc1bff690&user=joanofarctan&format=json')
data = response.json()
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!.. Thanks

Comment: Using json.loads (with the 's' at the end) instead of json.load fixrd my issue

Comment: Is there any particular preference between the two working solutions ? `data = response.json()` vs `data = json.loads(data)` ?

Answer (score 4):

[`requests.get(…).text`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.text) returns the content as a single (unicode) string. The [`json.load()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) function however requires a file-like argument.

The solution is rather simple: Just use [`loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) instead of `load`:

```
data = json.loads(data)
```

An even better solution though is to simply call [`json()`](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.json) on the response object directly. So don’t use `.text` but `.json()`:

```
data = requests.get(…).json()
```

While this uses `json.loads` itself internally, it hides that implementation detail, so you can just focus on getting the JSON response.

Comment: urgh just notice I had missed the "s" THANKS!