# Python parsing json file into something usable

Tags: python, json

Python 2.7

I am new to python and this is my first post for help.

I am sending a post request to the web and having a json file returned. It looks like this:

[json Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzIQs.jpg)

if i do:

> print data['result']

I get all the items listed

if i do:

> print data['result']['recordtype']

I get "list indices must be integers, not str" (because I need ['result'][0]['recordtype']? but that would limit it to only the first item)

I can get "some" info with:

> print(data['result'](type is a list)
>
> print(data['result'][0])(type is a dict)
>
> print(data['result'][0]['columns'](type is a dict)

But this only returns the first item. ([0]). Any other attempts gets me a "must be integer not str".

Ultimately, I would like to enter item "id" and have all the attributes "itemid", "displayname", "columns", etc returned for that item as variables. ("columns" will vary from json file to json but the rest should remain uniform)

Questions:

How can I loop through all these items based on the "id" value and return all the values associated with that item as variables?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [strange python issue, 'unicode' object has no attribute 'read'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040541/strange-python-issue-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-read)

Answer (score 0):

instead of `json.load()`, use `json.loads()`

[This error raised because the data is a unicode/str variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040541/strange-python-issue-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-read)

Comment: I have tried every combination of  json.dump/json.dumps - json.load/json.loads out and in.

Comment: if I use the out code "with open("C:\xxxx.json", "wb") as outfile:
    json.dump(conn.text, codecs.getwriter('utf-8')(outfile), ensure_ascii=False)"  when trying to bring it back in using "data = json.loads("C:\xxxx.json") I get - "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: if I use "data = json.load("C:\xxxxx.json")" in I get - "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"

Comment: if I change "dump" to "dumps" on the out code, nothing gets written to the file. (but no errors)

Comment: I fixed this issue by changing "data = json.loads("C:\xxxxx.json")" to "data = json.loads(open("C:\xxxxx.json").read())" I can now load the Json file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure something out. I pieced together this:

```
y = "user input id variable"
x = y

for i in data['result']: 
if i['id'] == x:
    NL_id = i['id']
    NL_Rc = i['recordtype']
    NL_Itid = i['columns']['itemid']
    break`
```

This returns the data from the json dict's I need in the way that I need it. Maybe this will help someone else like myself. (fifth day in python = total noob).

Answer (score 0):

Using the json python library should work.
Each element in the json is a dictionary. For each dictionary the value can be a string, a dictionary (etc) or also an array (collection of elements).
To access the value of a dictionary with key `k` you do `d['k']`. If its value is an array then you specify the index: `d['k'][0]`

As example take the following json file:

```
{"menu": {
  "id": "file",
  "value": "File",
  "popup": {
    "menuitem": [
      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
    ]
  }
}}
```

and play with this code `menuitem` is an array:

```
import json

f = open("test.json")
a = f.read()
jj = json.loads(a)
print(a)
print(type(jj))
print(type(jj['menu']['popup']['menuitem']))
for el in jj['menu']['popup']['menuitem']:
    print(el['value'])
```