# Trying to implement jsonschema with just filepaths

Tags: python, json, django, file

I've uploaded a json from the user and now I'm trying to compare that json to a schema using the jsonschema validator.  I'm getting an error, ValidationError:  is not of type u'object'

Failed validating u'type' in schema

This is my code so far:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect


import jsonschema
import json
import os
from django.conf import settings

#File to store all the parsers

def jsonVsSchemaParser(project, file):
    baseProjectURL = 'src\media\json\schema'
    projectSchema = project.lower()+'.schema'
    projectPath = os.path.join(baseProjectURL,projectSchema)
    filePath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,'src\media\json', file)
    actProjectPath = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,projectPath)
    print filePath, actProjectPath
    schemaResponse = open(actProjectPath)
    schema = json.load(schemaResponse)
    response = open(filePath)
    jsonFile = json.load(response)
    jsonschema.validate(jsonFile, schema)
```

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32040541/strange-python-issue-unicode-object-has-no-attribute-read) except instead of using a url I'm using my filepath.

Also I'm using python 2.7 and Django 1.11 if that is helpful at all.

Also I'm pretty sure I don't have a problem with my filepaths because I printed them and it outputted what I was expecting. I also know that my schema and json can be read by jsonschema since I used it on the command line as well.

EDIT: that validation error seemed to be a fluke. the actual validation error I'm consistently getting is "-1 is not of type u'string'". The annoying thing is that's supposed to be like that. It is wrong that sessionid isn't a string but I want that to be handled by the jsonschema but I don't want my validation errors to be given in this format: [image: this format]. What I want to do is collect all validation errors in an array and then post it to the user in the next page.

Comment: You changed your problem. Let me change my answer based on your current issue. But please remember, don't do like this. Many people can answer based on your question. So if you will change later. It will not make any sense for the readers. Any way good. No issues.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani Yeah, sorry about that, I realized that as soon as I posted it and tried to change it right away.  But even with that I'm getting errors.

Comment: Okay, it seems you are new to stackoverflow. It happens first time. Let's see your problem.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani Would you be so kind to look at the edit I just put in?

Comment: **@Talha**, can you please try to change 4th and 2nd lines from last to `schema = json.loads(schemaResponse)` and `jsonFile = json.loads(response)` then update   me. If it works then I will update my answer with explanation and references otherwise we will need to look for other solutions.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani It gives me a TypeError: expected string or buffer.  My validation error is right. It's what I want. It's just that I don't want it to break my page.

Comment: Can you please use try-except block or debug to find the 1st line causing the error. It will help us a lot.

Comment: If you want to store validation errors in a list then try-except statement is an excellent choice for you.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. I just try caught a validation error. I can add an answer with my code.

Comment: Okay, just try that and let me know if I could help you and let me edit my answer too. Great job.

Comment: **@Talha**, please format the code of your answer. Indent it. I edited but still it is not properly indented.

Comment: @RishikeshAgrawani That's proper indentation. Also don't add semicolons. Semicolons aren't used to end lines in python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up putting a **try-catch** around my validate method. Here's what it looks like:

```
validationErrors = []

try:
    jsonschema.validate(jsonFile, schema)
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as error:
    validationErrors.append(error)
```

EDIT: This solution only works if you have one error because after the validation error is called it breaks out of the validate method. In order to present every error you need to use [lazy validation](https://python-jsonschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validate/#jsonschema.IValidator.iter_errors).  This is how it looks in my code if you need another example:

```
v = jsonschema.Draft4Validator(schema)
for error in v.iter_errors(jsonFile):
    validationErrors.append(error)
```

Answer (score 0):

✓ **try-except-else-finally** statement is a great way to catch and handle exceptions(Run time errors) in Python.

✓So if you want to catch and store Exceptions in an array then the great solution for you is to use **try-except** statement. In this way you can catch and store in any data structure like lists etc. and your program with continue with its execution, it will not terminate.

✓ Below is a modified code where I have used a for loop which catches error 5 times and stores in list.

```
validationErrors = []

for i in range(5):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(jsonFile, schema)
    except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as error:
        validationErrors.append(error)
```

✓ Finally, you can have a look at the below code sample where I have stored **ZeroDivisionError** and it's related string message in 2 different lists by iterating over a for loop 5 times.

> You can use the 2nd list **ZeroDivisionErrorMessagesList** to pass to template, if you want to print messages on web page (if you want). You can use 1st also.

```
ZeroDivisionErrorsList = [];
ZeroDivisionErrorMessagesList = list(); # list() is same as [];

for i in range(5):
    try:
        a = 10 / 0; # it will raise exception
        print(a);.  # it will not execute
    except ZeroDivisionError as error:
        ZeroDivisionErrorsList.append(error)
        ZeroDivisionErrorMessagesList.append(str(error))

print(ZeroDivisionErrorsList);
print(); # new line
print(ZeroDivisionErrorMessagesList);
```

» Output:

```
[ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',), 
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',), 
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',), 
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',), 
ZeroDivisionError('division by zero',)]

['division by zero', 'division by zero', 'division by zero', 'division by zero', 'division by zero']
```

Comment: So there's actually a problem with this method. It only works one time. I think we need to use some sort of loop in order for this to catch every validation error.

Comment: **@Talha**, you can use a simple for loop and place your code inside that. It will not break if your code inside **except** block does not raise any **Exception**. I have added an example in my answer. You can have a look on that. Please let me know if you still have some issues.